# Order an array into a specific order in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have 3 arrays that look similar to this:

```
Array(
    [1] => Array(
            [id] => BISHO123362
            [branch] => 0
            [department] => 1
     )

   [2] => Array (
           [id] => 1
           [branch] => 0
           [department] => 1
     )
);
```

The each of the arrays differ very slightly but I don't think that this will have a cause any issues with an answer.

Say each of my arrays are title array_one, array_two, array_3.

Hoe would I put this into a new array in a particular order, for example:

```
new_array = 

Item from array 1
Item from array 2
Item from array 1
Item from array 3
```

then looping from the top all the way till there no items left in the original arrays?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the expected result here. Can you add that, too?

Comment: So array 1 has double size of array 2 and 3? Or what should happen when there is nothing left in one of the arrays?

Comment: its just 1 array with 2 sub arrays, not 3 arrays.

Comment: The 3 arrays do all vary in size, when it has used up all of one array then I think that it should continue doing what it can just missing that the array that has been exhausted?